# USB port strange behavior / Unknown USB Device (Code 43)

Tags: usb, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a Microsoft Surface Pro, running windows 10 Pro. My USB port (the one and only) suddenly appeared to have a problem. Every device I connect (e.g. mouse, printer, hard drives, flash drives), I get error Code 43 (Unknown USB Device) EXCEPT two of my hard drives that reads normally.

Anyone has any idea what should I try? The problem is that Surface Pro has only one USB port so it's very important to make it work again.

P.S. It's not possible to remove the battery and try this thing "remove battery and hold power button for a minute, then plug in battery again" because of surface construction.

[image: Capture 1]

[image: Capture 2]

Comment: Sounds like a hardware (or cable, or connector) problem: Communication is so bad that even requests to get the descriptor fail, except for some device which have particularly strong electrical signals (or something).